# Is there anywhere that has really cheap confluence WIKI hosting

Tags: hosting, wiki

i run a non profit and i see that Atlassian has free licenses for non profits for Confluence WIKI.  But my issue is hosting.  do you know if there is anyplace that has very cheap hosting rates and support hosting confluence WIKI.

Comment: I have to ask, I use Confluence at work and I hate it. Why do people pay $$$ for this sub-par wiki? Mediawiki, Deki, XWiki and so on are much better, in particular for templates -- you can't do WP-style templates in Confluence, and that sucks.

Comment: For an NPO why not use mediawiki? Or dokuwiki? Confluence isn't any better.

Comment: Really? I think Confluence beats any free wiki hands down, and it's immediately obvious when you a) see a wiki built with Confluence and b) work with it, eg they have a true WYSIWYG editor, not one of these "it's only what you see if you click on preview" WYSIWYG. Check out some pages created with confluence like Adaptavist: http://www.adaptavist.com

Answer (score 4):

Atlassian offer hosting for open source, and non profit organizations on case by case basis. I suggest following this link and submitting an application.

http://www.atlassian.com/software/views/opensource-license-request.jsp

*disclaimer: I am currently an Atlassian employee, although have no influence over the vetting process for not for profit hosting applications*

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue except in my case I just want it for personal use so can't even claim 'non profit status'. Anyway my rummage of confluence hosting services came up with these.

To poster 1, I have tried all of the wikis you mention and its horses for courses - each has merits and demerits. Dekiwiki offer a free - albeit small - hosted service. Xwiki is promising, does have install issues but more integration of functionality would be neater IMO. Mediawiki is just boring and not so pretty IMO. Confluence can be made to work well, but might involve the likes of Adaptavist to make it work to your liking. If you work with MSOffice then Confluence is the wtg IMO.

Hosting I've found these with my comments (to myself for reference)
1. Atlassian Small Business hosting
Pricing starts at $50 for 10 users, www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/hosted/
More info, confluence.atlassian.com/display/CSH/Confluence+Hosted+for+Small+Business+-+Resources
with limited support for plugins and macros. No custom themes supported.

2. Atlassian Enterprise hosting
   Pricing starts at $150pm, www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/hosted/
   and findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m0EIN/is_2007_Oct_29/ai_n21067363/
   More info, confluence.atlassian.com/display/EHOSTING/Frequently+Asked+Questions
3. 16 degrees hosting
   16degrees.com.au/index.php/confluence-services
   starts at AUD40
   but no support for plugins or themes.
   RAM is 128M with $10 per extra 128MB
4. Xtraordinary hosting
   www.xtrahost.co.uk/atlassian/confluence.html

If you're willing to do nearly everything yourself then look into a VPS with IMO at least 384M RAM and preferably 512M and upwards if you expect to run someplugins.
As far as VPS goes you'll need to find a hoster which support Java hosting, not all do. 
Its usually cheaper to host on Linux that it is to host on Windows.
One's that come to mind and seem to have potential (they're on my shortlist at least) - I 
don't recall the URL so Google them.
Mediatemple
A2 hosting
DailyRazor
if you're not going to run 24x7 then maybe check out Atlassian's blog on hosting on Amazon AWS

I currently run a Windows VPS from commercialnetworkservices in NYC and I can recommend them. They also do Linux, but havent tried them on that. I was hoping to pay < $40 for Linux

there are of course plenty other hosting co's that could work, these just happen to be the one's I've decided are worth a 2nd look, so YMMV and caveat emptor!

One that I'm also thinking of on the VPS side is
www.xtrahost.co.uk/xenvps/

since they also host Confluence as another service offer in theory they should be able to offer some support - maybe at a $ - if you need help on your own VPS held with them on that front.

Good luck,

If you do find someone you're happy with please post back, since I'd like to know too.

Comment: I'm running a Centos 5 VPS with 800 MB of RAM for Confluence 3.3, works great. I also use plug-ins like graphviz and have a CMS on the same Tomcat instance.  (I had problems with an instance of 423 Mb memory in particular MacGenMemory needs to be set at 100Mb and MySQL, Tomcat, Apache needs some space too).

Comment: NOTE: Confluence Small Business hosting has been discontinued.

Comment: "XWiki has install issues" - can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Atlassean also provides hosting (see http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/hosted/) but I can imagine that this is too expensive for a non-profit organisation.
But more importantly, what are your requirements? Will you expect lots of visitors? Do you need lots of bandwidth? How about disk space? Would you manage with only 500 MB of disk space? Or would you need over 50 GB? Do you want a specific database server too? Confluence needs a proper database setup but seems to support multiple database servers.
As a suggestion, wouldn't it be just easier to take some old computer from somewhere, install Linux or Windows+IIS on it and use that as web server? Confluence can be installed as a stand-alone system and do it's own hosting as it will install Apache Tomcat to serve it's pages.

There are plenty of cheap and even free hosting companies but getting this software installed on one of those hosts might be a problem. You'd probably need to look for a host that supports J2EE too, as an additional limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this link too

List Of Confluence & JIRA Hosting Providers

http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=162718

Have fun,

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Any VPS should do. There are absurdly cheap these days.

Comment: can you recommend one ?

Comment: I use OVH, but they are European. They are dirt cheap. Slicehost and Linode are other popular options. But really, pick a short contract and if you don't like it, switch...